# HTMLLoader / StageWebView Memory Leak

Tags: actionscript-3, air

When creating an instance of StageWebView, if you switch between multiple sites you'll notice that the amount of memory used slowly goes up. This isn't an issue if you're viewing 2/3 sites, but when it comes to creating an AIR application with a built in browser, I've now hit a brick wall in terms of memory management.

No matter what I do

- StageWebView.dispose() after each call
- Reset stage

The problem persists. Each load of a web page will increase memory by 3mb, which gradually increases to over 1gb and crashes the application.

I have no event listeners on the StageWebView instance. I hold absolutely no references to it. The memory just does not fully reset after the 2nd URL loads.

This can be seen by running the below in AIR:

```
package kazo
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.media.StageWebView;
    import mx.controls.Button;
    import mx.core.UIComponent;
    import flash.system.System;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author KM
     */
    public class Controller extends UIComponent
    {

        private var stageWeb:StageWebView;
        private var url:uint = 0;

        private const URL_ARRAY:Array = [
            'http://www.mmo-champion.com/',
            'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/',
            'http://www.twitch.tv/riotgames/',
            'http://www.stackoverflow.com/'
        ]

        /**
         * 
         */
        public function Controller() 
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param   e
         */
        private function init(e:Event):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            stageWeb = new StageWebView();
            stageWeb.stage = stage;
            stageWeb.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 80, width, height - 50);

            var btn:Button = new Button();
            addChild(btn);
            btn.label = 'Load URL';
            btn.x = 0;
            btn.y = 10;;
            btn.width = 100;
            btn.height = 30;
            btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, load);

            btn = new Button();
            btn.label = 'Try to GC';
            btn.x = 150;
            btn.y = 10;;
            btn.width = 100;
            btn.height = 30;
            addChild(btn);
            btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tryGC);

            /// 26,576k
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param   e
         */
        private function load(e:MouseEvent):void {
            if (!stageWeb) {
                stageWeb = new StageWebView();
                stageWeb.stage = stage;
                stageWeb.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 80, width, height - 50);
            }               

            stageWeb.loadURL(URL_ARRAY[url % 4]);

            url++;
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param   e
         */
        private function tryGC(e:MouseEvent):void {
            stageWeb.stage = null;
            stageWeb.viewPort = null;
            stageWeb.dispose();
            stageWeb = null;
            System.gc();
        }

    }

}
```

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Using a deprecated global method like setInterval and using anonymous function is hardly a way to demonstrate a memory leak. Maybe it's more a way to show up your code style which likely leads to memory leaks.

Comment: I'll write something up as legitimate code at the weekend. I'm not able to post production code. It feels like some of the cache is remaining in the memory, I wasn't able to find a way around it.

Comment: StageWebView has been around since AIR 2.5, if it was generating memory leaks so easily I think we would know it by now.

Comment: @BotMaster Updated. Run the above code and look at the memory usage on load. Then, click load URL 4 times and let each URL fully load. Then, click Run GC. Now compare the two memory values.

Comment: For comparison, I get 25,460k on boot and 75,600k after GC.

Comment: Where do you get those numbers btw? I would simply run that via Scout which will show you simply everything going on! (Scout is part of Adobe subscription)

Comment: Windows Task Manager.

Comment: Thrown a bounty on here to draw some attention.

Comment: Based on what I've found googling... https://forums.adobe.com/message/4008374 what happens if you add a reload call before disposing?

Answer (score 2):

I did some minor changes to your code to make it compilable with AIR 14 SDK (ASC 2.0, no flex), I build & tested the air application with

`mxmlc -optimize=true +configname=air Controller.as && adl Controller.xml`

and watched memory usage with Adobe Scout

Memory after GC was stable, stabilizing at 14481 kB

You may add `-advanced-telemetry=true` option to mxmlc to track allocations/deallocations precisely, just think to push the "hide cleaned objects" switch and select a range beetween two GC. You will see some object are not released immediatly, but you'll also see that if you select several of those ranges at the same time, those temporary leaks do not add up, which explains why memory does not increase constantly, in a GC environment, memory leaks are not really memory leaks

How do you measure memory usage ?

I checked memory usage of the adl process, it was higher ( > 100MB ) and less stable, but still stabilizing somewhere between 110 and 120MB after GC. In any case, it was definitely not  looking like it was going to increase up to 1 GB

Just remember that ActionScript GC is lazy and keeps pool of objects for future reuse, any application doing more than hello world will have sometimes strange memory behavior, which is part of the way AVM2 is working.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.media.StageWebView;
    import flash.system.System;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author KM
     */
    public class Controller extends Sprite
    {

        private var stageWeb:StageWebView;
        private var url:uint = 0;

        private const URL_ARRAY:Array = [
            'http://www.mmo-champion.com/',
            'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/',
            'http://www.twitch.tv/riotgames/',
            'http://www.stackoverflow.com/'
        ]

        /**
         * 
         */
        public function Controller() 
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param   e
         */
        private function init(e:Event):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            stageWeb = new StageWebView();
            stageWeb.stage = stage;
            stageWeb.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 80, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight - 50);

            var btn:TextField = new TextField();
            btn.selectable = false;
            addChild(btn);
            btn.text = 'Load URL';
            btn.x = 0;
            btn.y = 10;;
            btn.width = 100;
            btn.height = 30;
            btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, load);

            btn = new TextField();
            btn.selectable = false;
            btn.text = 'Try to GC';
            btn.x = 150;
            btn.y = 10;;
            btn.width = 100;
            btn.height = 30;
            addChild(btn);
            btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tryGC);

            /// 26,576k
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param   e
         */
        private function load(e:MouseEvent):void {
            if (!stageWeb) {
                stageWeb = new StageWebView();
                stageWeb.stage = stage;
                stageWeb.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 80, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight - 50);
            }               

            stageWeb.loadURL(URL_ARRAY[url % 4]);

            url++;
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param   e
         */
        private function tryGC(e:MouseEvent):void {
            stageWeb.stage = null;
            stageWeb.viewPort = null;
            stageWeb.dispose();
            stageWeb = null;
            System.gc();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The issue comes when you expand the Array from 4 domains, to 400 domains (or, allow domain entry). Because the memory settles down, but doesn't reset, you will never get through all 400 of the domains before you hit maximum memory. The maximum URL's I have ever managed to hit before capping out on memory is 117, at which point the memory was at 1.15gb. That said, I am aware (and agree) that Scout does not report the same memory that Windows Task Manager does. Unfortunately, it seems Task Manager is correct, as once you start hitting the 1gb mark, it does very shortly after, crash.

Comment: Actually, what you said now makes sense. Having repeated the test, using only those 4 domains, whilst it does initially start at 33mb, it does increase to 95mb after all 4 are loaded and after GC will always reduce back down to 95mb. My problem is that storing *that* much data just from hitting URLs isn't feasible for my project. Is this an inherent flaw just with how GC works in AVM2, meaning it can't be circumvented? At the moment I have a BAT file which is called after 100 URLs that closes the application and reopens it where the user left off (not a good process to have).

Comment: Actually, I did a quick experiment, changed the url list to just google.com removed the try gc button, improved resizing of the stage to enable maximizing the window size, and used it as a basic single tab browser all day long . It works pretty well, I had not a single crash, memory consumption never went above 200MB which is pretty reasonable compared to classic browsers, I tried a few heavy facebook flash game using Stage3D, etc. From my point of view, as long as you keep the same StageWebView instance, there is no memory issue

Answer (score 0):

This is just a random passer-by's <s>thoughts</s> ramblings.. note: I did not get to test-run your code since I've not got access to Flash at this moment. Nor do I back my rambling 100% (I know it's a WTF? but please read on, hopefully something useful in there..)

In your function `tryGC(e:MouseEvent):void` you set `stageWeb = null;` which is fine but then in your function `load(e:MouseEvent):void` you say **"If stageWeb is null then make a new one"**. Well since you previously set Flash to consider that one `null` it obediently creates a new one in memory (with the old memory imprint still possibly not yet garbage collected (just in the queue for it) Therefore it looks like ram usage has increased.

The whole `tryGC` thing is kinda flawed if you are then going to load other pages immediately after. The garbage collection (possibly) never happened since there's also a Mouse Event lurking around that says `if (!stageWeb) { //etc }` so basically you're switching its status to `null` but it cant be truly removed cos something else is using a reference to it and that something could be called up anytime in the future so it just sticks around in memory (with a `null` status)..

**Possible solutions:**

**1)**  In your function `tryGC` remove the mouse listener for load URL

```
private function tryGC(e:MouseEvent):void {
stageWeb.stage = null;
stageWeb.viewPort = null;
stageWeb.dispose();
stageWeb = null;
btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, load);
System.gc();
}
```

Now wait a few seconds and check is the ram usage dcreased? If it helps load at least 10+ urls before trying GC since you wont be able to load URLs via clicking. This is just for testing to see if the mouselistener was an issue for garbage collector

**2)** What you really need is a way to clear/overwrite the current url content/cache... not recreating new HTML page views. That does nothing helpful in this case. I think your problem stems from this also... [History Forward/Back](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html#historyBack())... I suspect each url load is adding to the history, and history in turn is more of a "content cache" instead of just a "string with previous URL". 
 Considering your plans for a BAT file... well that would open 100 urls, cache them in turn, but your viewport only show one item at a time (with 99 others pages held in memory, fully loaded & ready for instant display..). I don't know of a workaround for this. There is no `stageWeb.unloadURL();` or even `stageWeb.clearCache();` I didn't look hard enough but somebody out there on this planet knows a trick (and hopefully) blogged about it...

Comment: This doesn't work, but your answer effectively saying it's a cache makes sense. There just seems to be absolutely no way to clear it.